# Windows partition unreadable after installing Linux

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, grub, uefi, kali-linux

Basically I bought a new laptop. From one of the disks I made 3 partitions one for windows sdb4, one for linux sdb5 and one for rest of the staff sdb6. To install Kali Linux I had to change boot setting in BIOS from UEFI to Legacy, as when I got to boot manager in UEFI there was not even one boot option, whole menu was empty.  After installing Linux Grub did not see my windows.

I tried Os-prober that returned me nothing. I tried update grub,  anyway did not help. Besides that I had access to that partition I tried to restore mbr by using these two commands.

sudo apt-get install mbr 
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda

And now, when I turn on the PC I get

MBR FA:

And that is all PC got stuck on this moment.

When I use

sudo fdisk - l I get respond that /dev/sdb4/(windows partition) type is microsoft basic data.

So how can I restore access to that partition without losing amy data? And have can I make dual boot?

I downloaded Windows 8.1 to repair it by Windows tools, but even then I get MBR FA: So I can not turn on my PC. Please help me. :<

Comment: Is the partition unreadable, or can you just not boot from it? If it is readable, try and run a GRUB repair disk. I've had a similar issue which was fixed by this. It is actually GRUB that isn't properly installed and therefore doesn't recongnise Windows. Alternatively, you might have to reinstall Windows in Legacy mode to get everything to work.

Comment: Partition is unreadable. When I go into gparted, it shows that pqrtition file system as unknown, and I can not even open it.  Can I install Windows 8 while in legacy mode? When I run boot repair on USB it shows me Windows 8 boot files but there is info thwt I need UEFI to boot it.  When I go into UEFi I got info that there is no OS on a PC.

Comment: Have you tried adding this disk as a second disk in another PC? Or tried booting from a live disk and seeing if you can access the disk then? By the way: It's now not very clear what exactly you have done, when you did it and what was still working at that time. You say you cannot boot, but you also mention linux commands you tried. This makes it confusing.

Comment: Yeah I was trying a lot of different commands to make Windows work together with Linux, and I screwed up something.  Like I installed MBR in wrong disc or something.  If I will have to I will just format the whole disc and start from the beginning, but I am worried about the boot menu. It is empty in UEFI can it means that there is some hardware problem?

Comment: My previous comment still holds,. It's not clear what is and isn't working for you now. Can you still boot into Linux? Or do you get the MBR FA error immediately after the BIOS?

Comment: I was getting MBR FA after booting in both modes. Now I used boot repair disk, and I got message that operating system is missing.

Comment: I would appreciate if you try a bit better to read what I write. Let me make it simple: can you or can you not boot into Linux right now?

Comment: Sorry, no i couldnt boot into linux. Right now, as I am tired of looking for solution I formated whole disc, and I putted PC into UEFI mode with usb stick windows and I can not boot even the usb stick. Boot option menu is empty.

Comment: So that is weird, as I mentioned before UEFI is not really working on my PC.  I formatted everything, and when I was trying to install windows through legacy on the same drive I got a message that this drive do not support legacy.  But the second one is so I am re installing everything on other hard drive.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I can imagine that it didn't work on the first drive if your Linux distro only works with legacy, which the drive does not support. Not too weird that everything was then a bit messed up for Windows too. Just post a new comment if you have any news.

Comment: Your drive has GPT-partition-table, Windows can install only in UEFI-mode on this drive unless you convert drive to MBR. You have to install both systems in the same mode (UEFI or legacy). Grub boot-loader can not handle dual-boot with OS installed in different mode.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with **step 1**: you want your data back. If possible try to either boot the computer from an external USB drive or put the drive in another computer, see if you can get the data from there.

**Step 2**. Set your bios to legacy mode (or create an UEFI bootable Kali Linux[1]. You want to install both windows and Linux. I'd first install Windows and create all the partitions you need during that install. After installing Windows, install Linux. Now you should be fine.

PS. in the case you still encounter problems with recognising Windows in GRUB, don't repair Windows, but repair GRUB instead.

[1] https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux